# Shifting a string of characters?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that solves Caesar ciphers in C++. It takes a string of the alphabet and shifts it to the left each loop: "abc....yz" --> "bcd.....yza". The problem is after another loop it goes: "bcd.....yza" --> "cde.....yzaa".

```
char temp;       // holds the first character of string
string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
while (true)
{
    temp = letters[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (i == 25)
        {
            letters += temp;
        }
        letters[i] = letters[i + 1];
        cout << letters[i];
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Copy and paste that code and you'll see what I'm talking about. How do I fix this mysterious problem?

Comment: Could make `temp` a simple plain `char`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need letters to be 27 characters, not 26, and instead of `letters += temp` (which grows the string every time), use `letters[26] = temp[0]`.

...at which point you can just ditch `temp` entirely:

```
string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.";
while (true)
{
    letters[26] = letters[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {

        letters[i] = letters[i + 1];
        cout << letters[i];
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

[edit]

Although the more natural way to handle this is to use arithmetic on the characters themselves.  The expression `'a' + ((c - 'a' + n) % 26)` will shift a char `c` by `n` places Caesar-style.

Comment: This is awesome. Since the alphabet is only 26 chars long, what happens to that 27th char?

Comment: It's just there to hold a copy of the first character before you clobber it.  Since you never print it out, it does not really matter...  But I still think arithmetic on the characters themselves is cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, your loop does precisely the same as the following code:

```
letters = letters.substr(1,25) + letters.substr(0,1);
//        [skip 1, take 25]    + [first char goes last]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this easily using [`valarray< char >::cshift(n)`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/valarray/cshift/) (cyclical shift) method.