# How do I increment letters in c++?

Tags: c++, char, encryption

I'm creating a Caesar Cipher in c++ and i can't figure out how to increment a letter.

I need to increment the letter by 1 each time and return the next letter in the alphabet. Something like the following to add 1 to `'a'` and return `'b'`.

```
char letter[] = "a";
cout << letter[0] +1;
```

Comment: Did you try this? What happened?

Comment: Sorry this was just a quick example to highlight what i was trying to do, the program code seemed a bit irrelevant.

Comment: @Tomalak, it wasn't before user1095463 edited the question.

Comment: @user1095463: Sounds a little like a homework? If it is, please mark it as such

Comment: @user1095463: What seems irrelevant to you may not be irrelevant to us; that's why you're the questioner and we're the answerers!

Comment: Thanks for the help, answerer's! Got that part working now just need to sort out the wrap around when it reaches 'z'. Once again thanks :)

@nyarlathotep Not homework yet, just research for homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This snippet should get you started. `letter` is a `char` and not an array of `char`s nor a string.

The `static_cast` ensures the result of `'a' + 1` is treated as a `char`.

```
> cat caesar.cpp          
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char letter = 'a';
    std::cout << static_cast<char>(letter + 1) << std::endl;
}

> g++ caesar.cpp -o caesar
> ./caesar                
b
```

Watch out when you get to `'z'` (or `'Z'`!) and good luck!

Comment: This relies on implementation defined behavior, since C and C++ don't guarantee that the alphabetical characters are contiguous.

Comment: Surely ASCII and Unicode standards have this covered?

Comment: Yes, it does, but C is designed to portable–this means it runs on computers that may not be fortunate enough to use ASCII or Unicode.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - Saagar Jha is correct.    There are real-world standardised character sets, and C++ implementations that work with them.  With such implementations, your solution will not work.   For people who are willing to *assume* ASCII or Unicode your solution is fine, but such code will be a bug waiting to be exposed at run time (since it would not be diagnosed by a compiler) when ported to another system.

Answer (score 4):

It works as-is, but because the addition promotes the expression to `int` you want to cast it back to `char` again so that your IOStream renders it as a character rather than a number:

```
int main() {
   char letter[] = "a";
   cout << static_cast<char>(letter[0] + 1);
}
```

#### [Output](http://codepad.org/7OA997I6): `b`

Also add wrap-around logic (so that when `letter[0]` is `z`, you set to `a` rather than incrementing), and consider case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **'a'+((letter - 'a'+n)%26);**
assuming after 'z' you need 'a' i.e. 'z'+1='a'

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       char letter='z';
       cout<<(char)('a' + ((letter - 'a' + 1) % 26));

       return 0;
    }
```

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6171969/8511215

Answer (score 3):

Does letter++ work?
All in all char is a numeric type, so it will increment the [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/).
But I believe it must be defined as `char letter` not an array. But beware of adding one to 'Z'. You will get '[' =P

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    char a = 'a';
    a++;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

This seems to work well ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
char letter = 'a'; 
cout << ++letter;
```

Comment: This just outputs `a` and afterwards increments `letter`.

Comment: Yeah, fix it. (-1 it's kinda harsh, isn't it?)

Comment: I'd like to remove my -1 but it's locked now unless the answer is edited :-(

Answer (score 2):

waleed@waleed-P17SM-A:~$ nano Good_morning_encryption.cpp
waleed@waleed-P17SM-A:~$ g++ Good_morning_encryption.cpp -o Good_morning_encryption.out
waleed@waleed-P17SM-A:~$ ./Good_morning_encryption.out
Enter your text:waleed
Encrypted text:
jnyrrq
waleed@waleed-P17SM-A:~$ cat Good_morning_encryption.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    int main() {

    //the string that holds the user input
    string text;
    //x for the first counter than makes it keeps looping until it encrypts the user input
    //len holds the value (int) of the length of the user input ( including spaces)
    int x, len;

    //simple console output
    cout << "Enter your text:";
    //gets the user input ( including spaces and saves it to the variable text
    getline(cin, text);
    //give the variable len the value of the user input length
    len = (int)text.length();
    //counter that makes it keep looping until it "encrypts" all of the user input (that's why it keeps looping while its less than len
    for(x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    //checks each letts (and spaces) in the user input (x is the number of the offset keep in mind that it starts from 0 and for example text[x] if the user input was waleed would be w since its text[0]
    if (isalpha(text[x])) {
    //converts each letter to small letter ( even though it can be done another way by making the check like this if (text[x] =='z' || text[x] == 'Z')
    text[x] = tolower(text[x]);
    //another counter that loops 13 times
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 13; counter++) {

    //it checks if the letts text[x] is z and if it is it will make it a
    if (text[x] == 'z') {

    text[x] = 'a';

    } 
    //if its not z it will keeps increamenting (using the loop 13 times)
    else {


    text[x]++;

    }

    }
    }
    }
//prints out the final value of text
    cout << "Encrypted text:\n" << text << endl;
    //return 0 (because the the main function is an int so it must return an integer value
    return 0;

    }
```

Note: this is called caeser cipher encryption it works like this :

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
so for example my name is waleed
it will be written as : JNYRRQ
so its simply add 13 letters to each letter

i hope that helped you

Comment: Caesars Chiffre is +3 not +13 btw.

Answer (score 1):

It works but don't forget that if you increment 'z' you need to get 'a' so maybe you should pass by a check function that output 'a' when you get 'z'.

Answer (score -1):

cast letter[n] to byte* and increase its referenced value by 1.

Comment: Why would you cast before incrementing?

Comment: There is no such type in C or C++ ... You're thinking of Java or C# right now.