# Unexpected results when printing array and char to screen with cout

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

As a beginner of learning C++, I am trying to understand the difference between an array of type `char` and an array of type `int`. Here is my code:

```
void IntArray () {
    int array[5] = {5,6,7,8,9};

    cout << "Print int array: " << array << endl;
    cout << "Print int array[0]: " << array[0] << endl;
    cout << "Print int array[0]+1: " << array[0]+1 << endl;
}

void CharArray () {
    char array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0'};

    cout << "Print char array: " << array << endl;
    cout << "Print char array[0]: " << array[0] << endl;
    cout << "Print char array[0]+1: " << array[0]+1 << endl;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Print int array: 0xbfd66a88
Print int array[0]: 5
Print int array[0]+1: 6
Print char array: abcd
Print char array[0]: a
Print char array[0]+1: 98
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the following output the string '0xbfd66a88'? I was expecting it to return the address of the first element in the array:

   ```
   cout << "Print char array: " << array << endl;
   ```
2. Why does the following output '98'? I was expecting it to output the letter 'b':

   ```
   cout << "Print char array[0]+1: " << array[0]+1 << endl;
   ```

Comment: Uhh, it's not mine. I retracted my close vote ...

Comment: The differences are you are seeing are because `std::ostream` has different overloads for `char` than for `int` . Not because there are differences between the array behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

### 1.

Because `char` arrays are treated differently to other arrays when you stream them to `cout` - the `<<` operator is overloaded for `const char*`. This is for compatibility with C, so that null-terminated `char` arrays are treated as strings.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/501816/1227469).

### 2.

This is due to [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion). When you call the binary `+` with a `char` (with value 'a') and an `int` (with value 1), the compiler promotes your `char` to either a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`. Which one is implementation specific - it depends on whether `char` is signed or unsigned by default, and which `int` can take the full range of `char`. So, the `+` operator is called with the values '97' and '1', and it returns the value '98'. To print that as a `char`, you need to first cast it:

```
cout << "Print char array[0]+1: " << static_cast<char>(array[0]+1) << endl;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487255/1227469).

Comment: Your explanation of part 2 isn't right. When the non-overloaded `+` operator is used, the *default argument promotions* apply before the step that you are talking about. All integral types narrower than `int` are promoted to `int`.   For example, `'A' + 'B'` also has type `int` (not `char`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Can you clarify how that contradicts what I wrote?

Comment: you said that since `char` and `int` mismatch, there is a decision to be made to convert one to the other. That isn't true; the default argument promotions happen first (whether or not there is a mismatch). If your logic were right then `'A' + 'B'` would be a `char`.

Comment: @mattmcnabb Ok thanks. I've edited my question to take into account your comment, and also to point out that the `int` may be either `signed` or `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's go over each separately.

```
Print int array: 0xbfd66a88
```

Here you print an int[] which goes into the `operator <<` overload that takes int*. And when you print a pointer you see a memory address in hexadecimal format.

```
Print int array[0]: 5
```

Here you print the first element of the array which is an `int`. As expected.

```
Print int array[0]+1: 6
```

Here you add 1 to the first element of the array and print the result, which is still an `int`. 5+1 becomes 6. No mystery here.

```
Print char array: abcd
```

This is a bit trickier. You print a `char[]` and there is a special overload for `operator <<` that takes a `const char*` and that one gets called. What this overload does is print each character beginning from the address where the pointer points until it finds a terminating zero.

```
Print char array[0]: a
```

Here you print a `char` so the overload that takes `char` gets called. It prints the corresponding ASCII character, which is 'a'.

```
Print char array[0]+1: 98
```

Here the result of `operator+` is an `int` because the literal 1 is an `int` and the `char` value gets promoted to the wider type (`int`). The result is 98 because the ASCII code of the letter 'a' is 97. When you print this `int` you just see the number.