# Loop for increasing ascii value

Tags: c++, loops, ascii

I want to change my `char` to another `char` by adding a  number.

```
int n;
cin >> n;
str[i] = str[i]+n;
```

The problem is: i want to do it in a loop.
for exam :

> n = 4 ;
>    str[i] = Y ;
>   answer should be : C ;
>   how can i create this loop ?

Comment: Have you been slacking?

Comment: FYI, "exam" isn't a contraction of "example", but "examination". Anyway, why do you want to write a loop to perform an addition? Is it supposed to do something else?

Comment: How do you figure `'Y'` should become `'C'` by adding `4`? And what do you want to loop over? Plus, _assuming_ ASCII encoding is a bad habit to get into...

Comment: when we increase 'Y' (ascii code ) by 4 in cycle of Uppercase it become 'C' !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i increment letters in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487255/how-do-i-increment-letters-in-c)

Comment: By loop I think you mean modulo addition.

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you want with `%`

```
str[i] = (str[i] - 'A' + n) % 26 + 'A';
```

26 because there are 26 letter in the alphabet

Comment: ...except where they aren't. There are things like ÄÜÖ, or [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding... that's why I intensely dislike course material that does this kind of stuff because "it's easy".

Comment: there are other characters but i don't think that what OP cares about

Comment: @Tyker It's still bad practice to make assumptions on the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 0 to A 1 to B and simillary

```
int a=s[i]-'A'
```

now you can add n to it and find its mod with 26(no of alphabets)
y is 24  n=4 then (24+4)%26 = 2 so we can see 3 is C
the code is

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
int a=s[i]-'A';
a=(a+n)%n;
s[i]=(char)(a+65);//ascii value
}
```